# SSIS Execute Package task is slow to start running the first time

Tags: performance, ssis

I'm migrating an SSIS package from SQL Server 2012 to a new 2022 server.  The package uses the Execute Package task inside a loop to run another package in the project.  I'm finding that the first time the Execute Package task is run it seems to be taking a rather long time for it to start, and I don't know why or where to look for a cause.

The relevant part of the main package is this:

[image]

Looking at the execution times, the first time the Generic Parsing package is called, it takes over 10 seconds (the final column in ms), but the components of the package take only a fraction of that time.  Subsequent executions of Generic Parsing (also shown in the results) run as expected, without that initial delay.

[image]

Comment: What does "Generic Parsing" actually do?

Comment: I haven't looked in detail, but it basically looks what type of file it is that's being received, ready for further processing later.  This delay is being experienced with ALL packages though, not just this one.  The first time any package is executed (within that specific context) it is slow to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was due to the packages being imported into the new server without first being compiled for SQL Server 2022.  I presume that each package had to be recompiled on the fly every time that it was called, leading to the delay.

I would have thought there would be something more obvious surfacing in the logs to show that was the issue, but I couldn't find anything other than a couple of 'information' messages stating that "XXX has been migrated. The package must be saved to retain migration changes". Still, once the packages were recompiled and redeployed, the issue went away.